# Exact solution of the transport equation, Neumann boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, linear-pde, transport-equation

Please, can anyone give me some examples of the exact solution of the following Pde with the corresponding functions f and g. I need these to know if my code of an approximation scheme is correct or not.

$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\partial_{t} u+ \partial_{x} u=f(x,t), & t \in(0, 1), x \in(-1, 1) \\
u(0, x)=g(x), & x \in(-1, 1) \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0, & x=1,x=-1,t \in(0, 1)
\end{array}\right.$$

For $f=0$, the exact solution will be $u(x,t)=g(x−t)$, my problem is that I can't see why this solution should necessarily verify the Neumann boundary conditions.

Comment: for $f=0$, the exact solution will be $u(x,t)=g(x-t)$, my problem is that I can't see why this solution should necessarily verify the Neumann boundary

Comment: Excuse me if I write something stupid, we have $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(t,x)=g\prime(x-t)$ so if $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0, x=1,x=-1,t \in(0, 1)$. we get 
 $g\prime(1-t)=0$ and $g\prime(-1-t)=0$. I can't see why

Comment: I believe that the problem isn't well posed.  If $f=0$, the only $g$ that seem to be compatible with the boundary conditions are the constant functions.